# style-loader on webpack in production

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I am new to the Node.js application as well as webpack. During development I would run webpack-dev-server to serve up my bundles and it would create style tags and put all of the css on there. How would I get the css to be placed in the style tags on a production server since I can't run webpack-dev-server?

Answer (score 4):

The `style-loader` does not depend on `webpack-dev-server`, it simply adds your CSS to the bundle such that it will inject a `<style>` tag into the `<head>`, hence its name. As long as you're still using the `style-loader` for your production build, it will work exactly the same.

Because depending on the JavaScript bundle to be loaded before the CSS is getting injected has some drawbacks, there exists [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin), which extracts the CSS from your bundle, giving you a CSS file you can add to your HTML, so you can request/serve CSS separately from the JavaScript bundle.

Comment: I see. I have used the extract-text-webpack-plugin to extract the CSS to its own bundle but I was trying to use webpack to get the CSS into the style tags. If I run the webpack-dev-server, then I would see the CSS in the style tags but if I don't run the webpack-dev-server, then I do not see any of the CSS at all. Does this mean I have to install node.js on the production server for it to work?

Comment: If you use the `extract-text-webpack-plugin` you need to include the created CSS in the HTML file you serve (in addition to the JavaScript bundle). You're probably not using the same configs for development and production, hence the difference.

Comment: I will do that, seems like a much simpler route. Thanks!